# Match element with specific element not working JList ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I'm working on a program that takes an array of contacts and I'm trying to return an integer of how many people are online. I already have a button called refresh that is implemented. I press the "refresh" button on a JFrame and it will refresh the JLabel onlineCountNum which is a empty string at first. After pressing refresh, it shows up 1 to include the user that was online. However, when I log in another user and pressed the refresh button, it doesn't increment but stays at 1 for that user. The JList listContacts has elements with either the name or name(Online). I'm trying to count how many of those have name(Online). If the user is the only one on the server, it should show 1 as the result. If there are two people on the server, it should show 2 for both people and both would see another person as name(Online) on a pane.

```
private JLabel onlineCountNum;     //label gets refreshed by button
private JLabel onlineCountText;    //"Online Count: " label
private JButton onlineCountUpdate; //refresh button

onlineCountText = new JLabel("Online Count: ");
onlineCountNum = new JLabel("ERROR");
onlineCountUpdate = new JButton("Refresh");
onlineCountNum.setText("");

onlineCountUpdate.addActionListener(new MyButtonListener6());

class MyButtonListener6 implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int count = 1;
        ListModel list = listContacts.getModel();
        for(int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++){
            if(list.getElementAt(i).equals(list.getElementAt(i)+"(Online)")){ //possible source of error
                count++;
            }
        }
        onlineCountNum.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(list.getElementAt(i).equals(list.getElementAt(i)+"(Online)"))
```

Yes, this *is* the source of error...

Now, suppose:

```
list.getElementAt(i) == "someName(Online)"
```

What you check for, in the if statement, is:

```
list.getElementAt(i) == list.getElementAt(i)+"(Online)"
```

Which is like checking:

```
"someName(Online)" == "someName(Online)(Online)"
```

So it will always return false.

---

What you have to do is:

```
if(list.getElementAt(i).endsWith("(Online)"))
```

Comment: I edited my code accordingly and I'm presented with this error, cannot find symbol, when compiling. It refers to the .endsWith method.

Comment: Actually, I found my mistake. I forgot to specify the type of JList. However, your code still works! Thanks!